# How to use Gstreamer OpenCV plugin on Windows

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to build a simple program using GStreamer using the faceblur plugin that can be found in https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad **on Windows**.

As a starting point I used the first tutorial : https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=c

I have modified the pipeline as follows :

```c
  GError* error = NULL;
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch("autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! faceblur ! videoconvert ! autovideosink", &error);
  // print errors
  if (error != NULL) {
      g_error("Could not create pipeline: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free(error);
  }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the faceblur plugin here.

However, at runtime, the following error is thrown :

> ERROR **: 12:09:56.343: Could not create pipeline: no element "faceblur"

My question is : how to make this work **on Windows** ?
How to "install" the required plugin ?

I am using Visual studio for linking/compiling.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

When installing gstreamer on windows, you should select ALL plugins (or have a complete installation).